# Negative count in ActiveMQ pending message

Tags: activemq-classic, jmx

I am monitoring the ActiveMQ using jmx . i am using the below link to get the  ActiveMQ summary

```
http://localhost:8161/api/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost/BrokerId,TotalEnqueueCount,TotalDequeueCount,TotalConsumerCount,TotalMessageCount,TotalConnectionsCount,TotalConsumerCount,TotalProducerCount,MemoryLimit,MemoryPercentUsage,StoreLimit,StorePercentUsage
```

**At time T1**

I am sending the 100 message to ActiveMQ but i didn't dequeue any message.Now summary will look likes below

```
{
    "timestamp" : 1437996108,
    "status" : 200,
    "request" : {
        "mbean" : "org.apache.activemq:brokerName=localhost,type=Broker",
        "attribute" : ["BrokerId", "TotalEnqueueCount", "TotalDequeueCount", "TotalConsumerCount", "TotalMessageCount", "TotalConnectionsCount", "TotalConsumerCount", "TotalProducerCount", "MemoryLimit", "MemoryPercentUsage", "StoreLimit", "StorePercentUsage"],
        "type" : "read"
    },
    "value" : {
        "BrokerId" : "ID:synclap5489-54676-1437995895016-0:1",
        "TotalConnectionsCount" : 100,
        "TotalDequeueCount" : 0,
        "StoreLimit" : 104857600,
        "TotalConsumerCount" : 0,
        "TotalMessageCount" : 100,
        "TotalProducerCount" : 0,
        "MemoryPercentUsage" : 0,
        "StorePercentUsage" : 9,
        "TotalEnqueueCount" : 100,
        "MemoryLimit" : 739717939
    }
}
```

And stopped ActiveMQ server so 100 message in Pending status.

**At time T2**

Started the ActiveMQ again and sent another 100 message but not deque any message. Now Json data look like below

```
{
    "timestamp" : 1437996721,
    "status" : 200,
    "request" : {
        "mbean" : "org.apache.activemq:brokerName=localhost,type=Broker",
        "attribute" : ["BrokerId", "TotalEnqueueCount", "TotalDequeueCount", "TotalConsumerCount", "TotalMessageCount", "TotalConnectionsCount", "TotalConsumerCount", "TotalProducerCount", "MemoryLimit", "MemoryPercentUsage", "StoreLimit", "StorePercentUsage"],
        "type" : "read"
    },
    "value" : {
        "BrokerId" : "ID:synclap5489-55183-1437996657303-0:1",
        "TotalConnectionsCount" : 100,
        "TotalDequeueCount" : 0,
        "StoreLimit" : 104857600,
        "TotalConsumerCount" : 0,
        "TotalMessageCount" : 100,
        "TotalProducerCount" : 0,
        "MemoryPercentUsage" : 0,
        "StorePercentUsage" : 9,
        "TotalEnqueueCount" : 100,
        "MemoryLimit" : 739717939
    }
}
```

**After Deque**

After dequeue all message i am getting json data like below

```
{
    "timestamp" : 1437997015,
    "status" : 200,
    "request" : {
        "mbean" : "org.apache.activemq:brokerName=localhost,type=Broker",
        "attribute" : ["BrokerId", "TotalEnqueueCount", "TotalDequeueCount", "TotalConsumerCount", "TotalMessageCount", "TotalConnectionsCount", "TotalConsumerCount", "TotalProducerCount", "MemoryLimit", "MemoryPercentUsage", "StoreLimit", "StorePercentUsage"],
        "type" : "read"
    },
    "value" : {
        "BrokerId" : "ID:synclap5489-55183-1437996657303-0:1",
        "TotalConnectionsCount" : 101,
        "TotalDequeueCount" : 200,
        "StoreLimit" : 104857600,
        "TotalConsumerCount" : 1,
        "TotalMessageCount" : -100,
        "TotalProducerCount" : 0,
        "MemoryPercentUsage" : 0,
        "StorePercentUsage" : 9,
        "TotalEnqueueCount" : 100,
        "MemoryLimit" : 739717939
    }
}
```

TotalDequeueCount  changes to 200 TotalEnqueueCount remains 100 TotalMessageCount changes -100.

**My question :**

Why i am getting negative value in TotalMessageCount ?

Why this happen only when broker has been restarted with pending message ?

How to resolve this ?